# Using LinkedIn API to retrieve advertising reports

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm working on a simple app to programmatically retrieve ads performance within Linkedin. I have general API experience but this is the first time i get my feet wet with the Linkedin API.

One example from Linkedin API documentation suggest something that would get me started:

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.year=2016&timeGranularity=MONTHLY&pivot=CREATIVE&campaigns=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:112466001

I am encountering two problems:

First this example implies that you already know the campaign ID. However I am unable to find a way to retrieve a list of campaign ID's for a given account.

Second, if I manually pull a campaign ID, I receive an error: "{"serviceErrorCode":2,"message":"Too many fields requested. Maximum possible fields to request: 20","status":400}". Pretty clear error.
A little research tells me that by adding the parameter "&fields=" I will be able to limit my query to less than 20 field (I really need only a dozen anyway) but I can't find and documentation regarding the names of the fields available.

Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, with a few attempts i found an answer to my first question:
Basically this url will provide what I was looking for:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search&search.status.values[0]=ACTIVE&sort.field=ID&sort.order=DESCENDING&fields=id,name,status

In this case I limit the result to only 3 fields and only retrieve active campaigns, it seems to work.

I'm still looking for a list fo fields for the campaign performance.

Answer (score 0):

please refer the link below scroll down where you ill see the field names mentioned as metrics , these are the fields.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?tabs=http#analytics-finder

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.